# ELMAH mail failure problem

Tags: asp.net, elmah

Elmah recovers from routine exceptions (like the DB not configured for Elmah) quite well by doing nothing, or causing nothing to happen, but when I have ErrorMail enabled, and mail is not configured properly, I pick up an exception in my web site.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We re-wrote ErrorMailModule.cs to change the execution path around sending emails to avoid this, and configured ELMAH to use our own version.

Comment: That option is looking quite attractive right now, especially while I'm busy in the Elmah source adding an EF log to replace the SQL log

Comment: It's a shame it doesn't fail safely. Seems like a weakness in the design to me.